# Remove strings before a numeric value but not If contains PO BOX address or Suite Number in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column `street_address` with strings that looks like this:

```
id | street_address
----------------------
 1 | 3510 WILSHIRE BLVD #1500
 2 | PO BOX 29043 
 3 | RE HIAM S ABU QARTUMI 4676 ADMIRALTY WAY STE 632
 4 | RE: SOON, LEE YEE 3510 WILSHIRE BLVD #150
 5 | LAW OFFICES OF JOE M DOE 133 SANDSTONE ST STE 901
 6 | SUITE 940, 1500 N CENTRAL AVE
```

I want to remove the text before the numeric values (actual address), but need to exclude PO Boxes and the address that begins with Suite number. 
I want the output to be something like this:

```
 street_address
----------------------
 3510 WILSHIRE BLVD #1500
 PO BOX 29043 
 4676 ADMIRALTY WAY STE 632
 3510 WILSHIRE BLVD #150
 133 SANDSTONE ST STE 901
 SUITE 940, 1500 N CENTRAL AVE
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

Thanks everyone for the help!

However, for my example I made it work by using `replace`

```
# When an address starts with a string, 
# remove that string though the first number 
# unless that string is similar to 'PO BOX' or 'SUITE'. 
# This catches variants like 
# PO BOX, P.O BOX, PMB, STE, Suite, ste, etc.
pattern = r"^(?![PO.\sBX]{2,}|[PMB]{2,}|[\d]|[SUITE])(\D+)(.+)"
df['str_addr'] = df['street_address'].str.replace(pattern,'\\2')
```

Comment: I have `df['street_address'].str.extract(r'(\d+.+$)')`, but this removes everything before the  numeric values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
r'^(?:(?!(PO BOX|SUITE|\d+)))([a-zA-Z :,]+)'
```

The first part uses a non-capturing group to identify rows that don't start with a number, "PO BOX", or "SUITE". The second part `([a-zA-Z :,]+)` captures the start of those addresses that were flagged by the first half of the regex. You can extract this capture group from the offending lines and strip them down to the address. Obviously, if there are more characters besides [a-zA-Z :,], add them to this bracketed list to grab them too.

Comment: while it's a neat idea with non-capturing group. The OP actually wants to capture those part. Plus, this does not seem to extract the second part of the address.

Comment: OP wants to remove these parts. Instead of extracting they could do a replace with an empty string.

Comment: @k-pekosh this doesn't do the job. I made this work  with replace `r"^(?![PO.\sBX]{2,}|[PMB]{2,}|[\d]|[SUITE])(\D+)(.+)"`